# How to customize the Date Picker UI?

Tags: wpf, datepicker

For weekend and holiday dates in the Date-Picker Control, I would want to apply a style. How do I get the Dates to have a custom style?

Comment: What I suggest you, is that you put some effort in to your own work

Answer (score 1):

You can find  [default DatePicker Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datepicker-styles-and-templates) here and modify it as you wish.